# What is the cxx folder under android in react native project

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, build

When I build the project for android there is a `cxx` folder created under `android/app/`. When I clean the project either through Android Studio or using `./gradlew clean`, this folder sometimes causes problems because the references are incorrect because I've changed libraries or something. So I have to manually delete this folder for the clean to go through. I'm not sure why the cleaning process itself is not taking care of this. So I was wondering what this folder is and how does it play into the process of building the app?